# Syncing a carddav server with a ldap server

Tags: openldap, webdav

I am searching for a possibility to sync a carddav server with a openldap server. practically i need something that can read the carddav and update the ldap server.

both , the carddav server and the openldap server ar on the same computer. The addresses in the carddav server are either VCARD VERSION 3 (*.vcf) or VCARD VERSION2  (*.ics) files.
The files are located in /var/lib/carddav and the OpenLdap server database is located in /var/lib/ldp/data.mdb.

Q&A Section:

1. What fields are you looking to sync from a CardDAV to an OpenLDAP?
   Answer:
   The Fields of a VCARD Version 2 or Version 3. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard
2. What is the CardDAV product?
   Answer:
   A address-book, or in LDAP language a user-list. The sync tool must connect to carddav and take the user-list and the data and move it to the ldapserver.
3. Are you using plain OpenLDAP or another product that uses it?
   Answer:
   plain OpenLDAP
4. Please provide extra info about the context and the objective, maybe the way of accomplishing it are not what you are thinking
   Answer:
   I want to sync the user-list. This means when I change something on the carddav it should sync the changing on the openldap. And vice-versa.

> Update 2020/07/27 I am still interested in this. I am now able to read
> the carddav server and detect new cards and copy them to a database.
> But I am not able to write the records to the openldap server. So now
> I would be interested to find any open piece of code who can read and
> write to openldap.

Comment: 1) What fields are you looking to sync from a CardDAV to an OpenLDAP? 2) What is the CardDAV product? 3) Are you using plain OpenLDAP or another product that uses it?  4) Please provide extra info about the context and the objective, maybe the way of accomplishing it are not what you are thinking.

Comment: Coincidentally, I am currently looking at a custom version of OpenLDAP using the slapd-perl backend and NET::CardDAVTalk to allow LDAP queries to a CardDAV address book. We only need it to read the CardDAV address book (it's for multifunction printers and SIP handsets) but if we can get it running that far we will open source the code.
Sadly we need to do this because we also need to run SAMBA4 in AD mode and have to ditch OpenLDAP for SSO authentication.